# Adding a library to a makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, static-libraries

I just installed [RtMidi](https://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/) for a project and compiled it. The examples in the `tests` folder work and so does my code if I put it in the folder and include it in the Makefile that compiles all the examples. How can I use RtMidi in a project with `#include <RtMidi.h>` instead of having my code in the tests folder? More specifically, what should I put in my Makefile? I've read a bit about dynamic and static libraries but I have no idea what I should be looking for. I've tried adding `-llibrtmidi` and `/usr/local/lib/librtmidi.a` without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a standard Makefile, the `CXXFLAGS` macro defines flags for the C++ compiler. You will need to add `-I<path to header directory>` to this macro for the compiler to find the RtMidi header files.

Then you will need to add `-L<path to lib directory>` to the link step of the Makefile so that `-lrtmidi` will find the library file. (Note that you omit the `lib` prefix for the `-l` command)

Comment: Thank you! That worked fine. Why do I have to add `-I/usr/local/include/` and `-L/usr/local/lib/` though? Doesn't the compiler look there for libraries by default?

Comment: Usually the compiler is configured to look in /usr/local by default -- but not on all systems.  Your system must be configured to not use /usr/local by default.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description of your environment, you may require something like

```
CPPFLAGS += -I/usr/local/include

LDFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib

LDLIBS += -lrtmidi
```

in your Makefile. `make` uses a lot of these [implicit variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html).